# Windows C: drive size

Tags: windows-server-2003, hard-drive

Our C: drive on some of our Windows servers is only 8GB, is there anyway to dynamically update this? Its all locally attached storage.

Thanks

John

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need a partition resize tool. Examples include [PartitionMagic](http://www.symantec.com/norton/partitionmagic), or the excellent [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/). The latter is a linux boot disc: boot, resize, sorted! Its also free, just remember to make a full backup just in case something goes wrong.

edit: as mentioned, Dynamic disks are a different matter for most resizing tools. If you want to resize a dynamic volume, you [use the diskpart utility](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325590) provided by Microsoft. This comes with Win2003. Please note that you cannot resize a dynamic volume if it was originally on a basic disk and was later upgraded to dynamic. Back everything up regardless before starting.

Comment: gParted is the best.

Comment: Is this easy enough to do with Raid configurations?

Comment: Yes, it will work with RAID configurations, assuming it is hardware RAID.  It might be possible with software RAID, but it would probably be much harder to perform than with hardware RAID.

Comment: I am mostly a Windows guy, but have found gparted to be easy and reliable.  I have used it on some of our W2000 servers where the OS partition is tiny.

Comment: If you see my answer below, you'll likely run into problems when trying to use gparted with Server 2003 and dynamic disks.

Comment: +1 on Backup first.  It is unlikely that something will go wrong, but you don't want to be "that guy" when you screw up the OS partition on an important production server.

Comment: Gparted is great, but has a hidden limitation. When resizing an NTFS partition from small (say, 30G) to large (say, 300G), you are likely to get a "disk read error" due to changes in the geometry stored in the Windows boot/partition scheme. For more information, search on the terms "ntfs partition resize disk read error"

Comment: yep, things can go wrong. In such a case I'd create a brand new partition and restore from the backup I made before resizing. If you're a l33t hax0r, you could follow these steps: http://fugitivethought.com/blog.php?action=view&blog_id=77 Impressive knowledge that chap has!

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of products which can do this. One Open Source solution is Gparted, which is a bootable Linux based application which can perform non-destructive re-partitioning. Always take a backup before such operations, just to be safe.

Answer (score 2):

If your disk is bigger than 8Gb you can use software like [Partition Magic](http://www.symantec.com/norton/partitionmagic), or [Acronis](http://www.acronis.co.uk/)  to extend the partition. However if your physical disk is only 8Gb, then your going to need to look at getting a new disk and using something like Acronis to image the old drive and move it to the new one.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to run into some issues if you are trying to resize a dynamic disk.  There are some tools out there that will allow you to convert the dynamic disk to a basic disk to resize it, but I'd be pretty leery of trying it.  take a look here:  http://www.partition-tool.com/easeus-partition-manager/copy-dynamic-volume.htm

Answer (score 1):

I recently used [Acronis Disk Director Suite](http://www.acronis.com/enterprise/products/diskdirector/) for that, works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 2000 introduce a new feature called dynamic disk.
It allows, amongst other things, to dynamically resize a partition. You can even extend your partition on another disk.

[This article](http://www.petri.co.il/difference_between_basic_and_dynamic_disks_in_windows_xp_2000_2003.htm) provides some usefull informations.

Comment: One thing to bear in mind is that many disk recovery tools will not work with dynamic disks.